# Google Script for Google Spreadsheet that, given two specific Sheet names, updates the dates from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1

Tags: google-sheets

I'm studying how to do that but I'm really just beginning and I find it very difficult to put in the code.

**The situation:**

I have 2 Sheets:

- In Sheet 1 i have  8 columns named "ID" "Date1" "Date2" "Date3" "Date4" "Date5" "Date6" "Date7" on the first row. *ID is a univocal String, dates are, well, dates.*
- In Sheet 2 I have multiple columns, that could be different and not in the same order, but among them, there will be the same "ID" "Date1" "Date2" "Date3" "Date4" "Date5" "Date6" "Date7" on the first row

**What do I need?**

The script should look for the first item in the column "ID" in Sheet 1, and search it in the column "ID" in Sheet 2. **If** it finds it, it should copy the dates values in the same row from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you need a script for this?

because it can be easily achieved with just a simple formula called `VLOOKUP`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D:D, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I'm not sure if it helps me.. this is a formula that finds certain values, i need to copy and paste values from sheet2 to sheet1.